# What does 'No renderer supporting SKP version 68 found. Rotation disabled.' mean and how do I resolve it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

I've upgraded to Android Studio 4.0 and am attempting to use the new 3D view of the Layout Inspector, but am unable to 'rotate it'. At the top of the tool window, there's a message reading "*No renderer supporting SKP version 68 found. Rotation disabled.*", which is apparently the reason. What does this message mean and how to I resolve it? I do have `Enable Live Layout Inspector` checked in `File > Settings > Experimental` and `Enable Live Layout Inspector` checked in the layout Inspector window.

**Update:** Part of the issue might have been that I was targeting SDK 28 and this is an API-29+ feature. When I changed the target SDK to 29, the "Skia Parser Server" component was automatically installed. But now the `Live Updates` checkbox is sometimes grayed-out and the message "Unable to detect a live inspection service, restart the device." is displayed if I hover on it. Restarting the device (Pixel 3 running API 29) has no effect. Other times, the checkbox is enabled (and checked) but nothing displays in the window.

Comment: SKP refers to the Skia graphics library. https://skia.org/user/release/release_notes I see the same error on API 29 and on API 30 it says "No renderer supporting SDK version *73* found."

Comment: There is a bug in the issue tracker now I would star it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157714512

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we need newer emulator image so we can run this. I guess soon there will be new release for API29.

Comment: I'm actually using fully updated Pixels ( 3 and 3XL), so it's not an emulator issue.